# Select com campo null PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Tenho o seguinte select

```
SELECT u 
FROM User u 
WHERE lower(u.fullname) 
      || lower(u.username) 
      || lower(u.email)) LIKE %:pesquisa%
```

Acontece que eu quero fazer a pesquisa por qualquer um dos 3 campos existentes, mas o email não campo obrigatório.

Se eu fizer uma pesquisa que não possua email preenchido ele não retorna  nada.

Comment: O que acha de adicionar um `|| u.email is null`?

Comment: olá bigown, segui sua sugestão, mas o que está pegando que eu esqueci de falar, é o hibernate, dê uma olhada na stacktrace. Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [SELECT u FROM User u WHERE lower(u.fullname) || lower(u.username) || lower(u.email) is null LIKE pesquisa]. Obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Não foi o que eu falei para usar, vou colocar a sintaxe completa: SELECT u FROM User u WHERE lower(u.fullname) || lower(u.username) || lower(u.email) || u.email is null LIKE %:pesquisa%

Comment: Obrigado novamente pela tentativa, mas a exception persiste, vou tentar outras alternativas.

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-conditional.html   use o COALESCE string nulas não concatenam.

Comment: Motta, já testei com o COALESCe, mas o hibernate não reconhece a função. Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Mude para o seguinte:

```
SELECT u 
FROM User u 
WHERE lower(u.fullname) LIKE '%:pesquisa%'
OR lower(u.username) LIKE '%:pesquisa%'
OR lower(u.email) LIKE '%:pesquisa%'
```

Comment: Olá Cigano, ainda continua com erro de sintaxe  EclipseLink, mas valeu a ajuda. Olhe a stacktrace: Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [SELECT u FROM User u WHERE lower(u.fullname) || lower(u.username) LIKE :searchString OR lower(u.email) LIKE :searchString]. 
[27, 121] The expression is not a valid conditional expression.

Comment: @Fernando Estranho. Não era pra dar erro. Atualizei a resposta.

Comment: Cigano, valeu pela ajuda, consegui fazendo da seguinte forma: @Query("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE lower(u.fullname) LIKE %:searchString% OR lower(u.username) LIKE %:searchString% OR lower(u.email) LIKE %:searchString%"), ficou meio gigante o select.

Comment: @Fernando Está igual ao da resposta. [Veja por favor o tour para entender o ciclo do site](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour). Obrigado!

Comment: O like não deveria ter ficado LIKE '%:pesquisa%' ?

Comment: @AllanRamos Sim, é verdade. Já corrigi.

Answer (score 0):

No hibernate não existe a função COALESCE, no lugar dela você deve usar a função nullif(column, 'Value if null')